# Display post format post in the sidebar

Tags: wp-query, sidebar, post-formats

I am trying to pull posts with the post-format of "quote" on my sidebar. I'm getting the code to spit out the else statement but that's about it so far. I am working in the roots theme if that helps at all. Let me know if I can show anymore code that might help you help me :). Thanks.

```
<div class="sidebar-quote">

  <?php

  $quote = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post-format',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( 'post-format-quote' )
                )
            )
        );
   ?>

  <?php
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $quote ); ?>

  <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php get_template_part('templates/content', 'quote'); ?>

 <?php endwhile; ?>

 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I would start by double-checking that you have at least 1 *published* post with the quote format.

Comment: Always a good reminder. Definitely have some in there @mrwweb

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob. I named the Taxonomy wrong... It's

```
post_format
```

not

```
post-format
```

Comment: Why did I get voted down for correcting myself?